# Used MacBook Pro crashing

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, macos, logs

I've just bought a new MacBook pro off craigslist and I'm having a few problems with it, it has crashed three times within two days. The last two crashes were just a few minutes ago and the second one happened almost immediately after it booted up from the first crash and reopened all the programs.

Here are the specs:

Early 2013 MacBook Pro Retina
500 GB internal SSD.

[image: specs]

Given these specs it really shouldn't be crashing. Can anyone help me understand why it's struggling so much?

As a note, this may or may not have something to do with it, I ran the hardware diagnostics (both the basic and comprehensive ones) and I got one and only one error: 
`4HDD/11/40000000: SATA(0,0)`

Here are the two last crash logs:

```
Anonymous UUID:       CE652574-7A26-82F5-11CD-2433068E0EC0

Sun Oct  9 15:19:20 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7fa9bcc982): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff9216e3d000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.13.60/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff924103ad80 : 0xffffff80266f748c 
0xffffff924103ae00 : 0xffffff7fa9bcc982 
0xffffff924103aee0 : 0xffffff7fa75255ca 
0xffffff924103afa0 : 0xffffff7fa75f8080 
0xffffff924103b000 : 0xffffff7fa75f812a 
0xffffff924103b030 : 0xffffff7fa78b71bc 
0xffffff924103b080 : 0xffffff7fa78b687a 
0xffffff924103b0f0 : 0xffffff7fa7624f66 
0xffffff924103b110 : 0xffffff7fa752c2f6 
0xffffff924103b1c0 : 0xffffff7fa7528f0a 
0xffffff924103b3c0 : 0xffffff7fa752b641 
0xffffff924103b4a0 : 0xffffff7fa8fe05c7 
0xffffff924103b580 : 0xffffff7fa8fe042e 
0xffffff924103b680 : 0xffffff7fa8fe16d0 
0xffffff924103b6c0 : 0xffffff7fa8fe0eed 
0xffffff924103b780 : 0xffffff7fa8ffe075 
0xffffff924103b7e0 : 0xffffff7fa8f4085a 
0xffffff924103b810 : 0xffffff7fa8ffe137 
0xffffff924103b830 : 0xffffff7fa8f027d3 
0xffffff924103b850 : 0xffffff7fa8f3e1ed 
0xffffff924103b870 : 0xffffff7fa8f19745 
0xffffff924103b8b0 : 0xffffff7fa8ff4c6e 
0xffffff924103b8d0 : 0xffffff7fa8fcf06b 
0xffffff924103b8f0 : 0xffffff7fa8fcc356 
0xffffff924103b910 : 0xffffff7fa8fcc2e9 
0xffffff924103b930 : 0xffffff7fa8fce0b2 
0xffffff924103b990 : 0xffffff7fa8f0e823 
0xffffff924103b9e0 : 0xffffff7fa8fcd5cb 
0xffffff924103ba30 : 0xffffff7fa8f067fc 
0xffffff924103bac0 : 0xffffff8026ce7d39 
0xffffff924103bb20 : 0xffffff8026ce5d62 
0xffffff924103bb80 : 0xffffff8026ceed31 
0xffffff924103bcc0 : 0xffffff80267c9968 
0xffffff924103bdd0 : 0xffffff80266fc23c 
0xffffff924103be30 : 0xffffff80266d9b51 
0xffffff924103be80 : 0xffffff80266ed6e7 
0xffffff924103bf10 : 0xffffff80267f600e 
0xffffff924103bfb0 : 0xffffff80266a9f66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.13)[27E0AFCE-E36A-35F5-A008-BB1EB3A2C7B9]@0xffffff7fa8f01000->0xffffff7fa8f91fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa6f52000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa7453000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.13.60)[CB03417A-9373-3817-BEC7-43F2EE6AF3F9]@0xffffff7fa9bbe000->0xffffff7fa9bd1fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.13.60)[C07B10D3-D474-3217-A17A-3D4F11F0282B]@0xffffff7fa9bb6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7fa7aaf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa6f52000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa7453000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[7D89A61E-ED4E-32C7-8CC2-1D5B7E76E498]@0xffffff7fa9bb9000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.2)[5DD89348-73FE-38C1-87A2-FE664001CBAA]@0xffffff7fa74b6000->0xffffff7fa77a7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa6f52000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C1544DFB-9066-340F-AD0A-9302DC3E6841]@0xffffff7fa749a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa7453000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.60)[FDEAB5E1-3BFF-34DF-92AB-6AE26C8405F7]@0xffffff7fa74aa000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.1.2)[D5475C72-21B8-356C-A904-78CD5AAEBA45]@0xffffff7fa77b8000->0xffffff7fa796afff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.2)[5DD89348-73FE-38C1-87A2-FE664001CBAA]@0xffffff7fa74b6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa6f52000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.1.2)[FC349F8C-5043-3B46-A796-6CC097BFB1B2]@0xffffff7fa8fa1000->0xffffff7fa9044fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa6f52000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C1544DFB-9066-340F-AD0A-9302DC3E6841]@0xffffff7fa749a000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.2)[5DD89348-73FE-38C1-87A2-FE664001CBAA]@0xffffff7fa74b6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa7453000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(288.13)[27E0AFCE-E36A-35F5-A008-BB1EB3A2C7B9]@0xffffff7fa8f01000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: prl_vm_app

Mac OS version:
16A323

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Mon Aug 29 17:56:20 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.32~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 622D2470-C34D-31F9-A62B-6AA9A3C6A3CD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000026400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8026600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8026500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 14244813065487
last loaded kext at 12660076875503: com.parallels.kext.vnic 11.2.2 32651 (addr 0xffffff7fa9e35000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 12795965612001: com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 5.0.0f18 (addr 0xffffff7fa9dd9000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.kext.vnic 11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   11.2.2 32651
com.avira.kext.FileAccessControl    1.2.2
org.pqrs.driver.VirtualHIDManager   1.1.0
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner   10.21.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.7
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   276.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   276.26
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.0f18
com.apple.GeForce   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.8
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  251
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 251
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 39
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.1.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1100.37.1a16
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   171
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 276.26
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.1.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   152
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.0f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.0f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.13
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.60
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0A, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Log from the second crash:

```
Anonymous UUID:       CE652574-7A26-82F5-11CD-2433068E0EC0

Sun Oct  9 15:23:05 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 7 caller 0xffffff7fabfcc982): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 5 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x0010a1c0: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xc0000000 0xffffff9219270000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P1/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.13.60/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 7), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82073e2d60 : 0xffffff8028af748c 
0xffffff82073e2de0 : 0xffffff7fabfcc982 
0xffffff82073e2ec0 : 0xffffff7fa99255ca 
0xffffff82073e2f80 : 0xffffff7fa99f8080 
0xffffff82073e2fe0 : 0xffffff7fa9cce7aa 
0xffffff82073e3050 : 0xffffff7fa9a7fe42 
0xffffff82073e30c0 : 0xffffff7fa9cd2e57 
0xffffff82073e3180 : 0xffffff7fa9a94560 
0xffffff82073e31b0 : 0xffffff7fa9becd37 
0xffffff82073e31e0 : 0xffffff7fa9be2f3b 
0xffffff82073e3280 : 0xffffff7fa9be34b5 
0xffffff82073e32e0 : 0xffffff7fa993c5e1 
0xffffff82073e3330 : 0xffffff7fa9be81a2 
0xffffff82073e3490 : 0xffffff7fa9be8807 
0xffffff82073e3530 : 0xffffff7fa993f3d8 
0xffffff82073e3560 : 0xffffff7fa9a37291 
0xffffff82073e35e0 : 0xffffff7fa9a36d8f 
0xffffff82073e3610 : 0xffffff7fa9a48553 
0xffffff82073e36e0 : 0xffffff7fa98fc3ed 
0xffffff82073e3740 : 0xffffff7fa98fb7bd 
0xffffff82073e3760 : 0xffffff7fa98fb3d2 
0xffffff82073e3810 : 0xffffff7fa98fb1ad 
0xffffff82073e3830 : 0xffffff7fa98e8aa4 
0xffffff82073e38d0 : 0xffffff7fa992a155 
0xffffff82073e3ad0 : 0xffffff7fa992adc1 
0xffffff82073e3bc0 : 0xffffff7fa9b1160f 
0xffffff82073e3c10 : 0xffffff7fa9b11e8f 
0xffffff82073e3cb0 : 0xffffff7fa98b8028 
0xffffff82073e3d40 : 0xffffff7fa989bfc8 
0xffffff82073e3dc0 : 0xffffff7fa989efb6 
0xffffff82073e3e00 : 0xffffff7fa98633d7 
0xffffff82073e3e40 : 0xffffff7fa9862476 
0xffffff82073e3e80 : 0xffffff7fa985e373 
0xffffff82073e3ee0 : 0xffffff80290bedbf 
0xffffff82073e3f30 : 0xffffff80290bd621 
0xffffff82073e3f80 : 0xffffff80290bcc06 
0xffffff82073e3fb0 : 0xffffff8028aa6af7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa9853000->0xffffff7fa988dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa9352000
         com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C1544DFB-9066-340F-AD0A-9302DC3E6841]@0xffffff7fa989a000->0xffffff7fa98a9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa9853000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa9352000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.13.60)[CB03417A-9373-3817-BEC7-43F2EE6AF3F9]@0xffffff7fabfbe000->0xffffff7fabfd1fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.13.60)[C07B10D3-D474-3217-A17A-3D4F11F0282B]@0xffffff7fabfb6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[4F7FB6AD-2498-3F71-827C-ED7AA4BF2511]@0xffffff7fa9eaf000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa9352000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa9853000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[7D89A61E-ED4E-32C7-8CC2-1D5B7E76E498]@0xffffff7fabfb9000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.2)[5DD89348-73FE-38C1-87A2-FE664001CBAA]@0xffffff7fa98b6000->0xffffff7fa9ba7fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa9352000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[C1544DFB-9066-340F-AD0A-9302DC3E6841]@0xffffff7fa989a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[377FAA09-C02F-3FF4-A5DE-C0F2E711C8B0]@0xffffff7fa9853000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.13.60)[FDEAB5E1-3BFF-34DF-92AB-6AE26C8405F7]@0xffffff7fa98aa000
         com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.1.2)[D5475C72-21B8-356C-A904-78CD5AAEBA45]@0xffffff7fa9bb8000->0xffffff7fa9d6afff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.2)[5DD89348-73FE-38C1-87A2-FE664001CBAA]@0xffffff7fa98b6000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[731443D8-78D5-30C8-939A-1ED3E857CA22]@0xffffff7fa9352000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
16A323

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Mon Aug 29 17:56:20 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.32~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 622D2470-C34D-31F9-A62B-6AA9A3C6A3CD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000028800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8028a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8028900000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 216797216160
last loaded kext at 114148063401: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa9780000, size 425984)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.kext.vnic 11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   11.2.2 32651
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   11.2.2 32651
com.avira.kext.FileAccessControl    1.2.2
org.pqrs.driver.Karabiner   10.21.0
org.pqrs.driver.VirtualHIDManager   1.1.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.7
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   276.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   276.26
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   276.26
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.8
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.0f18
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   251
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  251
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 251
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    540
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 39
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.1.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1100.37.1a16
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   171
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 276.26
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.1.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   152
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 276.26
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.0f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.0f18
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.0f18
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    288.13
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.60
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.13.60
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    540
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0A, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: Did you wipe and reinstall the OS or is this the OS that was loaded when you purchased the Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be graphic card related. 2011-2013 MacBook Pro have a problem with their graphic card, especially the dedicated one.

There exists a repair extension programme:

https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Go to your next applestore and have it checked.

Comment: The GPU panic seems worth ruining diagnostics whether this model has a repair extension program or not.j Worst case, mail in repairs might be $300 and then you could contact the seller for a refund or price adjustment if you need to pay for a repair right after you purchased the Mac.

Comment: For those wondering, it was indeed a hardware issue with a defective model. I took it in for repair and it was fixed for free. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Perfect! That is the reason why I advice to buy AppleCare. Mobile devices are today really integrated. Heat and other issues can be quite expensive very fast.

Comment: I would advice to do a proper stress test in order to find out if the repaired hardware keeps working. There are some websites where you can find the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this (returning / chasing hardware faults) you can boot the Macbook with a clean OS from a remote drive (or an installation DVD). This will indicate whether its a system / software issue rather than hardware - if the clean OS boots fine without a crash, it's not your hardware. Could save you time and expense.

If you don't have another OS to hand, try adding a new user with Admin rights but NO additional software. If this works the issue is limited to a an issue on the primary account. In the same vein, boot in safe mode - this will force diagnostics and turn all but essential software off - if the MacBook works OK in this mode, its another pointer to an OS / account / software issue.

It's worth noting that older Macs don't behave well with a significant OS update through migration assistant e.g. 10.7 to Sierra. You can end up with a mix of old and new components which often cause beach ball stalls and crashing. Any major OS update should be on a clean drive i.e. wipe / fresh install of the OS and software - the only way to have a fast, optimised system. Since you have bought the Mac used, don't assume the OS is a clean install.

In 20 years of maintaining Macs, 9 times out of 10, problems are (in this order):
• OS badly installed, updated or maintained OR unsuitable for the hardware (even if the latest OS will install, doesn't mean you should upgrade - performance most often drops, especially on Macbooks that are already de-tuned for heat, noise and battery life). 
• Ram - not enough, modern systems can use 4 to 6GB before you begin work
• fonts - too many, badly installed within the system folder, conflicting
• existing software incompatible with new OS
• startup items, including Akamai, Microsoft and Adobe updaters that run constant process in the background - turn them off. Use Utlities / Activity Monitor to see what is running in the background.
• web browsers running Flash especially with Safari on older MacBooks / OS's - will hog Ram, speed up the fans and reduce the MacBook to a crawl.
• language kits and printer support - delete all that you don't use - will save you 10+GB of HDD and potentially improve drive access speed.

I'm not saying it's not a graphics card issue or other hardware fault, although its worth discounting the common issues first, before you run to the expense of an 'expert' repair (or return).